# Portfolio optimisation with estimated positive and downside returns

Tags: portfolio-optimization

What are the approaches to optimise a portfolio where for each security the analyst specifies expected return (10%) and downside risk (-3%)?

Comment: It is a nice idea but does not take into account the interrelationship (correlations) among different assets.

Comment: You could create a covariance matrix using historical correlations and estimated variance...